# Java cambiar el valor inicial del método getSelectedRow()

Tags: java

Hola necesito quitarme la duda de si se puede cambiar el valor inicial no sólo de ese método sino de cualquiera. En este caso el método getSelectedRow() devuelve 0. Pero como hago para cambiar su valor inicial a 1?

Comment: Por favor, adjunta lo que llevas de codigo

Comment: Por favor, podrías adjuntar el código que llevas ya que ocupamos tener una referencia visual en la cual podamos probar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo estás hablando de un JTable.

Si es ese el caso, podrías crearte una clase que extienda al JTable y que sobreescriba el método getSelectedRow() para que al retornar le sume uno.

Ejemplo:

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
public class MyJTable extends JTable {
    @Override
    public int getSelectedRow() {       
        return super.getSelectedRow() + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Para el caso de estar trabajando con un JTable de SWING, debes primero acceder al `SelectionModel` de la tabla y luego definir el rango de filas que quieres seleccionar utilizando el método `setSelectionInterval()`.

```
jtable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(1, 1);
```

[JTable#getSelectionModel() JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel())

[ListSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval() JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionInterval(int,int))

En el caso de estar trabajando con un TableView de JavaFX, igualmente primero debes acceder al `SelectionModel` y luego indicar que fila quieres seleccionar con alguno de los métodos disponibles para este fin, por ejemplo el método `select()`.

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().select(1);
```

[TableView#getSelectionModel() JavaDoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSelectionModel())

[TableView.TableViewSelectionModel#select(int) JavaDoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html#select(int))

Comment: Muchas Gracias!